# haskell - print numbers from a list with text

Tags: haskell

I was trying to write a function that receives a number, and prints this text, for example, `elephants 5` prints the following:

```
If 2 elephants bother a lot of people, 3 elephants bother a lot more!
If 3 elephants bother a lot of people, 4 elephants bother a lot more!
If 4 elephants bother a lot of people, 5 elephants bother a lot more!
```

It starts by 1 or 2, and ends at the number that I gave.
I have done this:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad  

elephants n = 
    if ( n`mod`2 ==0 ) then do   
    colors <- forM [1,3..n] (\a -> do  
        putStrLn $ "If " ++ show a++ " elephants bother a lot of people,\n"++ show (a+1)++ " elephants bother a lot more!" 

        )  
    putStr "" 
    else do
    colors <- forM [2,4..(n-1)] (\a -> do  
        putStrLn $ "If " ++ show a++ " elephants bother a lot of people,\n"++ show (a+1)++ " elephants bother a lot more!" 

        )  
    putStr""
```

It prints the following:

```
> elephants 5
If 2 elephants bother a lot of people,
3 elephants bother a lot more!
If 4 elephants bother a lot of people,
5 elephants bother a lot more!
```

The part where I wrote `colors <- forM [1,3..n]`, the colors dont mean anything, it is just for the program to function. I know that this probably isn't the right way to do this; how could it be improved?

Comment: So, if I understand it right, the code actually works correcctly? And what you want is suggestions to improve it? Then it is more appropriate for our sister site [CodeReview.SE]. But, don't cross-post - if it should be on Code Review, flag your own post for moderator attention and ask for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The part where I wrote `colors <- forM [1,3..n]`, the colors dont mean anything, it is just for the program to function.

But that does mean something, it means roughly "foreach value from 1 to n counting by 2 (3-1) do this monadic action".

The obvious change would be to calculate 1 and 3 or 2 and 4 and use them in a single monadic event but fundamentally you aren't doing incorrect work there.